# two initialisations seperated by seperated by semi colon in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

```
for(i=1;i=-1;i++)
if(i<5) break;
printf("%d\n",i);
```

i was asked to write the output of the following code, i could not understand as the second argument should have been a condition, but here it was an assignment,

```
output: -1
```

i cant understand how it is possible, so i tried to experiment with the code

```
int i=1;
while(i=-1)
{
    printf("condition is true\n");
    if(i<5) break;
}
printf("%d\n",i);
```

the output of the following code is

```
output: condition is true
        -1
```

can anyone explain how the above two codes work
 and how is while(i=-1) evaluated to TRUE??

Comment: You *do* know the difference between assignment using `=` and comparison for equality using `==`? You also know that in C everything non-zero is *true*, and only zero is *false*? And what the `break` statement does? If there's anything of this you don't know, then find a good beginners book and start reading it from the beginning.

Comment: yeah i know the difference, but that was the question asked,, but when i=-1 is given in the condition, is the value assigned to 'i' and then evaluated to true?

Comment: The condition is `i = -1`. That will be fully evaluated, and the result of an assignment is the left-hand side after the assignment, that is `the value of `i` after the assignment, which is `-1` and which if non-zero and therefore true.

Comment: a warning should be issued

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you  for taking your time to explain, thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.: Just curious to know the reason of your commenting instead answering - I guess , is it because there is a tendency to dislike answers to these questions? or I am over thinking?

Comment: @coderredoc It always start out as a simple comment. Then I tend to expand it more and more through edits or through further comments. And I am kind of lazy sometimes. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.: Ah I overthought. Yes I know some authors over here doing this including you.(That I get to know now)

Answer (score 1):

The condition is always true. Because the value of an assignment statement is the value assigned. So `-1` is non-zero and non-zero value is considered as  true in [c](/questions/tagged/c) so it is always true.

The correct usage would be `==` which compares the value and returns `1` or `0` based on  the equality or non-equality.

So here when you did `i = -1` and put in the `while` loop condition - it boils down to

```
while( -1 ){
  ...
   /* break here */
}
```

And as `-1` is considered as true in [c](/questions/tagged/c) because of it being nonzero - the loop condition evaluates to true.

The `break` statement here is given here so that this loop doesn't turn to be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a `for` loop in C is

```
for(expr1, expr2; expr3)
    /* body of loop */
```

Now, conventionally, `expr1` is the loop initialization, and `expr2` is the condition under which to keep going, and `expr3` is the increment between loops.  But that's only a convention -- in actuality, the compiler just arranges to execute `expr1` once, then `expr2` to decide whether to take another trip through the loop or not, then `expr3` at the bottom of the loop.  So it's more or less equivalent to

```
expr1;
while(expr2) {
    /* body of loop */
    expr3;
}
```

Or, stated another way:

```
expr1;
while(1) {
    if(!expr2) break;
    /* body of loop */
    expr3;
}
```

But then the other key point is that, yes, the expression

```
i = -1
```

doesn't look much like a condition; it looks like an assignment.  But in C, when you use an expression as a condition (that is, in a context where what we care about is whether the expression is "false" or "true", all we really care about is whether the expression evaluates to zero or to non-zero.  And the value of an assignment expression is simply the value that was assigned.  So the value of

```
i = -1
```

is -1, and that's not zero, so it's interpreted as "true".  So if you say

```
while(i = -1) {
    /* body of loop */
}
```

the condition is always "true", so it will be an infinite loop, unless there's a `break` statement in the body somewhere (or a `return`, or a call to `exit()`, or something like that).

Answer (score -1):

First for loop one does nothing and will be removed from the generated code if the optimisation is on

Second one enters the loop one time. The actual loop will be removed by the optimising compiler and replaced by the puts, initialisation and printf call.

https://godbolt.org/g/T5wgqt

printf with the format string only is replaced by the puts

Comment: The for loop assigns -1 to `I`. That isn’t nothing. It ain’t much, but it ain’t nothing.

Comment: The OP wanted to know what the code *does*.  So these explanations of optimizations are irrelevant (and somewhat confusing).  Optimizations shouldn't affect what the code does, only how fast it does it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `i` will be wiped out as well if the optimisation is on.

Comment: Well, the value printed will be `-1` because of the assignment in the loop condition.  Thus, there is a vestige of the loop left in the result.  The loop is not ignored — it affects the generated output.